# Matrix identity involving inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse, block-matrices, schur-complement

Let matrix $Y \in \mathbb{S}^{n}$ be symmetric and positive definite (thus invertible) and $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $Y - X X^T \succ 0$. I think that the following identity should hold and I am trying to prove it (it works for $n=1$):

\begin{equation}
\bigg(X^T \left( Y - X X^T \right)^{-1}X + I \bigg)^{-1}= I - X^T Y^{-1}X.
\end{equation}

Do you have any idea or properties that could help me to prove it?

I observe that

$$I - X^T Y^{-1}X = \begin{pmatrix} Y^{1/2}&-X^T \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} Y^{-1} & 0 \\ 0 & Y^{-1}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}Y^{1/2}\\ -X\end{pmatrix}$$

but I am not sure it can help since I do not know how to invert such a "product of block matrices".

---

Edit : My observation is wrong, the right-handside yields $I + X^T Y^{-1}X$.

Edit: My problem is a particular case of the "Woodbury matrix identity".

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, why are you appending `Edit`s? Just refine the question!

Comment: Yes it works, just multiply what you are trying to invert on the RHS and use at some point $(Y-XX^T)^{-1} (Y-XX^T)=I$.